# Autocorrelation and auto regressive

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive

How related and inter changeable are these two ?  I am a beginner student of time series.. As far as I understand, AR is a model, while autocorrelation is a phenomenon. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is correct auto-correlation is a sequence of correlations taken at fixed intervals. If the auto-correlation decays while the partial correlation (conditional correlation ) cuts off after k values the model will be an AR model of order k.